# Как передать rsync пароль для подключения к удаленной машине?

Tags: ssh, usercontrol, rsync, password

Хочу использовать rsync для ежедневного резервного копирования папок и файлов с одного сервера на другой. Команду rsync запишу в .sh файл, например в таком виде:

```
rsync -v --delete --exclude-from=.git --delete-excluded root@127.0.0.1:/home/www/ /backup/rsync/www/
```

вопрос: **как передать команде rsync пароль для подключения к удаленной машине?**

Comment: А не нужно использовать пароли. Используйте ключи!

Comment: А где бы найти пример?

Comment: [В любом поисковике](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ssh%20авторизация%20по%20ключам)